# How to use a custom library for multiple projects on GitHub

Tags: git, include, github

So, here is a scenario.

Let's say I have a project called P1 which uses a custom library called MyLib. I'm also working on another project P2 which also uses MyLib. MyLib exists in one place and both projects include it.

Now, if I want to push those projects to github, is there a way to maintain this same structure? or will I have to create a copy of MyLib for each project?

Answer (score 1):

Git has [submodules feature](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html) that will allow you to define your MyLib repository as submodule for both of your projects. Of cause you need to separate your library for this to work.

After separating the library into its own repository you may add it as submodule for any your project on any path inside it.